# Adding items to the List at creation time in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, list, c#-to-vb.net

In c# I can initialize a List at creation time like

```
var list = new List<String>() {"string1", "string2"};
```

is there a similar thing in VB.Net?
Currently I can do it like

```
Dim list As New List(Of String)
list.Add("string1")
list.Add("string2")
list.Add("string3")
```

but I want to avoid boring .Add lines

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[VB10 supports collection initializers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/05/automatic-properties-collection-initializers-and-implicit-line-continuation-support-with-vb-2010.aspx). I believe your example would be:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
```

[MSDN has more information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617(v=VS.100).aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much!
That's exactly what I need. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in VS2008, so it's another reason to switch to newer VS. But anyway it's the answer: it's impossible in VB prior to VS2010

Answer (score 4):

You can also use AddRange if you don't want to put all of your items on a single line.

```
Dim list As New List(Of String) From { "string1", "string2", "string3" }
list.addRange({"string4", "string5", "string6"})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim a As New List(Of String)(New String() {"str1", "str2"})
```

Though if it's VB 2010 I'd definitely go with Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: thanks! Using "From" is better, but it's also nice workaround