# How Do I add Multiple Items to List automatically

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, visual-studio-2012

List :

```
Public LimoLijst As List(Of Limo)
    Dim _Limo1 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Black"}
    Dim _Limo2 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Pink"}
    Dim _Limo3 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo4 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "Yellow"}
    Dim _Limo5 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo6 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "Black"}
    Dim _Limo7 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Limo", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo8 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Limo", .Kleur = "Tuxedo Crème"}
    Dim _Limo9 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Porsche Cayenne Limousine", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo10 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Porsche Cayenne Limousine", .Kleur = "Electric Blue"}
    Dim _Limo11 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Mercedes SL 55 AMG", .Kleur = "Silver"}
    Dim _Limo12 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Mercedes SL 55 AMG", .Kleur = "Silver"}
    Dim _Limo13 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo14 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "White"}
    Dim _Limo15 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "Black"}
    Dim _Limo16 As New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "Black"}
```

I want to add them in a for loop by adding +1 to every _Limo name variable
SOmething like this

```
Sub New()

    For number As Int32 = 1 To 16

        LimoLijst.Add(trycast("_Limo" + (CType(number, String)), Limo)
    Next
End Sub
```

For some reason I cannot manipulate the variable name to add it everytime to the list.

I want the _Limo1 to add to the list. Then add one to the variable number and then
add _Limo2..and so one...Any ideas ?

Thanx

Comment: Can you explain why you need different `variable names`? Adding 1_Limo or 2_Limo makes no difference to the list content

Comment: The first limo the color is black..the second limo the color is pink...All limo's have diffrent properties. Some limo's are identical...but that is because i really need 2 of those in my list.

Comment: you dont need new vars for each (limo_1, limo_2); to get a specific one back from the list, your Limo class is going to need a Name property and/or use a `Dictionary(of String, Limo)` instead  ( `thisLimo = LimiList(Limo1)` isnt going to work ).

Comment: The complier will not retain the names you have used. Your code is equal to Public LimoLijst As List(Of Limo) = New List(Of Limo)() From {New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Black"}, New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Pink"} ... }

Comment: the only thing i want to avoid is to add every limo instance manually. Like LimoLijst.Add(_Limo1) LimoLijst.add(_Limo2)...I want the variable to count up until 16 in the for loop

Comment: you could serialize the fleet once and reload that way, but you will still have to write code to look for the "pink" "liNcoln", in order to get back a specific one; _Limo2 wont work.

Comment: You want to cast a string to a Class Limo?

Comment: Yes!! That's it!! But i have found a temporary solution Public LimoLijst As New List(Of Limo) From {_Limo1, _Limo2, _Limo3, _Limo4, _Limo5, _Limo6, _Limo7, _Limo8, _Limo9, _Limo10, _Limo11, _Limo12, _Limo13, _Limo14, _Limo15, _Limo16} But it would be cooler in a for loop!! x

Comment: Then the numbers add up from 1 to 16...but for that i need to extract the number

Answer (score -1):

Ok got it now I guess...

I changed this answer so people could see the good outcome.
Instead of declaring the variables first..i added them directly to the list like this

```
Public LimoLijst As New List(Of Limo) From {New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Black"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "Pink"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Licoln Limo", .Kleur = "White"}, _
                                               New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "Yellow"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "White"},
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Hummer", .Kleur = "Black"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Limo", .Kleur = "White"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Limo", .Kleur = "Tuxedo Crème"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Porsche Cayenne Limousine", .Kleur = "White"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Porsche Cayenne Limousine", .Kleur = "Electric Blue"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Mercedes SL 55 AMG", .Kleur = "Silver"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Mercedes SL 55 AMG", .Kleur = "Silver"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "White"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "White"}, _
                                                New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "Black"}, _
                                                 New Limo With {.Merk = "Chrysler 300C Sedan", .Kleur = "Black"}}
```

Comment: Same question goes here...I don't understand why 2 people disliked such a useful question. Apparently on this link..other people are looking for it to  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628223/adding-items-to-the-list-at-creation-time-in-vb-net

Comment: That Link is List(of String).  The stated question is convert class object to string.  This answer is not converting a class to a string.  Nor is it converting a string to a Limo class.

Comment: as before, you **do not** need to create 16 limo objects to fill the List.  If you have them as distinct object, why add them to a List?

Comment: Cause I thought that is what A list does. It contains objects of the same object type. If you create a list withouth objects inside of it..it's kinda useless right ?

Comment: yes, but you have **two** references to the same object for each Limo: `List(n)` and `_LimoNN`; you should be recreating a tmp Limo object 16 times and adding them to the `List<T>`

Comment: Can you give an example for one lime please about how to create such an object temporary and adding it to the list ? Cause I'm kinda confused. Thanx